# How to get iTunes playlist or entire library into program in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, itunes

I'm wondering how to get the iTunes library into a mac application using Cocoa? I want the user to be able to choose a song from the iTunes library and then play that song. How would I do this?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE. The answer to “how to make my program do X in Xcode” is “the same way as with any other text editor and build system”. You mean to ask about Cocoa.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Karelia Software's iMedia Browser framework](http://www.karelia.com/imedia/), which lets the user choose all sorts of things from the user's iLife libraries.

To play the song, you'll probably use NSSound.

Comment: Thanks but how do I integrate Karelia into my project? I downloaded the source and tried compiling it but it failed with a lot of errors.

Comment: You don't, because Karelia is a software company. If you're having a problem using the iMedia Browser framework, you should contact Karelia.

Comment: [How to integrate](https://code.google.com/p/imedia/source/browse/wiki/HowToIntegrate.wiki) Karelia